# ember-data 2.0 and many-to-many relations

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

How to handle many-to-many relations in ember 2.0 and ember-data 2.0?
It seems like hasMany relations must have a belongsTo on the other side.

I guess this is what is called polymorphic relations? I see some discussions on something like this, but that seems to be for an outdated version of ember-data?

```
author: belongsTo('book', { polymorphic: true })
```

What is the proper way to do this in the latest version of ember/ember-data?

One possible solution, as I see it, would be to specify the hasMany relation on one side and do not specify anything on the other side (drop the belongsTo completely) if I will navigate the relation only one way anyway.

**Edit:**
Based on the comments, I would like to clearify my question. I think I am not looking for polymorphic relations. I am looking for a way to model many-to-many relations.

For instance a book many have many authors and an author may have many books.

I have a model object (i.e. 'author') with a `hasMany` relation. I cannot say that my 'book' has `belongsTo` relation to an 'author'. But that's what the ember guides says I should.

I have tried:

```
//app/models/author.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    books: DS.hasMany('book')
});

//app/models/book.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string')
});
```

I.e. I tried to specify the relation only one way (because I need to navigate only one way) but that creates strange runtime errors.

Comment: A polymorphic relationship is when more than one type of model can represent a parent model. Imagine `user: belongsTo('user', { polymorphic: true })`, but instead of `user` you could have an `admin` model type, a `guest` model type, but they're all users.

Comment: There does not have to be a `hasMany` for every `belongsTo`.  It all depends on what you want to show in your application.  Comments could have a `belongsTo` with author, but if you don't need to list comments when accessing the `author` store, then you don't need a corresponding `hasMany`.